# Limiting CloudCode's access to certain projects on AndroidStudio

Tags: google-cloud-intellij

If I install Google Cloud Code on my AndroidStudio, and I want coding assistance in project A but NOT in project B (as I'm not allowed to expose Project B's code to third parties). I'm guessing that When project B is open in my IDE, the minute I start coding, CloudeCode will kick in and start making requests to a server, with the pieces of my code, for auto-completion, am I right? Can I disable this for project B only? can I deny access to projects/files/specific code segments?